# Would "You were welcome" imply that this isn't anymore the case?

Tags: interpretation

Someone told me he was thankful for being invited to my party.
I guess saying "I was thankful" is used because the party is now over, so the feeling of being thankful faded away.

Would I answer "You are welcome"?

Or would I have to answer "You were welcome"?

Im a little bit unsure, since "You were welcome" could imply in my understanding that I'm not welcoming it anymore.

Is that right?

Comment: *You are (you're) welcome* is a fixed phrase. A native speaker would rarely say the three word sentence *You were welcome*. The same goes for *You'll be welcome*, *you're gonna be welcome*, etc. We might use *welcomed* in these other tenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would answer, "You are welcome," because your sentiment is in the present. You are correct that "You were welcome" would imply things you don't intend. Don't worry; you have this right. (Also, see Peter's excellent comment, below.)

Comment: Another way to express "You **were** and **still are** welcome" is "You are **always** welcome".

Comment: @Peter- An elegant and appropriate suggestion. +1